# Google Apps Script: How to fix this for loop to insert paragraphs of one google document to another?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I'm arriving at last stops of my Apps journey (there'll be several others =).

The code bellow is a function that aims to do this: iterates through the paragraphs of one google text document and, when it finds in text some sinal, some paragraph (such as "Introduction", "Part 1 - Background" or "Part 2 - Biography") whose content is igual a `theses_type`, it inserts all `theses_type` paragraphs into the first document, after that sinal or `theses_type` keyword.
So, I'm trying to do this with the function "importTheses" (thanks @Serge insas and others for previous help!). But I'm having trouble after the line `for( var k = 0; k < thesesParagraphs-1; ++k )`. Even when I got through the log the boolean `True`, I can't get the paragraphs inserted. I also can't get the log of this line: `Logger.log("thesesDoc.getText() = " + thesesElement.getText() );`. So, any help or hint will be very appreciated.

```
function importTheses(targetDocId, thesesId, thesesType) { // just a name, I used it to analyse docs  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
  var targetDocParagraphs = targetDoc.getParagraphs();
  var targetDocElements = targetDoc.getNumChildren();

  var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
  var thesesParagraphs = thesesDoc.getParagraphs();
  var thesesElements = thesesDoc.getNumChildren();

  Logger.log("targetDocId = " + targetDocId);
  Logger.log("thesesId = " + thesesId);
  Logger.log("thesesType = " + thesesType);

  var elTargetDoc=[];
  var elTheses=[];

  for (var j = 0; j < targetDocElements; ++j ) {
       var targetDocElement = targetDoc.getChild(j);
       Logger.log("targetDoc.getChild(j) = " + targetDocElement);// to see targetDoc's content
       elTargetDoc[j]=targetDocElement.getText();
       if(elTargetDoc[j] == thesesType){
         Logger.log("elTargetDoc[j]== " + elTargetDoc[j]);
         Logger.log("thesesType " + thesesType);
         Logger.log("if(elTargetDoc[j]== thesesType)" + (elTargetDoc[j]== thesesType) );    
           for( var k = 0; k < thesesParagraphs-1; ++k ) {
               var thesesElement = thesesDoc.getChild(k);
               Logger.log("thesesDoc.getChild(k) " + thesesDoc.getChild(k));
               Logger.log("thesesDoc.getText() = " + thesesElement.getText() );             
               elTheses[k] = thesesElement.getText();
               targetDoc.insertParagraph(j, elTheses[k]);
           }
       }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       for( var k = 0; k < thesesParagraphs-1; ++k ) { .. }
```

In this line of code, you're intention is to loop using `k`, over integer values starting at 0. The loop should run at least once, as long as `thesesParagraphs` is 2 or more... *and is a number*.

That second condition is your problem. Earlier in the function, you had this:

```
var thesesParagraphs = thesesDoc.getParagraphs();
```

... so `thesesParagraphs` is an Array of Paragraph objects, not a number. You are probably interested in the count of paragraphs:

```
       for( var k = 0; k < thesesParagraphs.length-1; ++k ) { .. }
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

Or perhaps `thesesElements` was what you intended to use to bound your loop, since it's a number.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, @Mogsdad. You not only show my mistake but also have pointed a better way, ie, using `thesesElements`, which makes more sense (since some elements are not paragraphs). Thanks again!